# ERROR: path may not be null or empty string. path='null'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile rootProject.file(props.keyStore)
android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword props.keyStorePassword
android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias props.keyAlias
android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword props.keyAliasPassword
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text rather than images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I cannot see the `keystore.properties` file in your screenshot I assume you haven't created one?

You are trying to load the `keystore.properties` file but the file is missing. Therefore the property values are null, since no property file was loaded.
To solve this problem you must create a file named `keystore.properties` in the projects root directory. The content of this file should contain your keystore credentials.
This should look as follows:

```
keyStorePassword=storepw
keyAliasPassword=keypw
keyAlias=keyAlias
keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore-file.keystore
```